# How to select max time stamp for each group?

Tags: r

How to select max timestamp for each group in R.

```
     df <- read.table(text = " ID   obj MR_time
        1599    1   20:05:22
        1599    1   20:06:38
        1599    1   20:07:22
        1599    2   20:08:38
        1599    2   20:09:28", header = TRUE)

dt <- data.table(df)
```

I required output to be

```
1599    1   20:07:22
1599    2   20:09:28
```

Answer (score 1):

We convert it to `DateTime`, and get the index by group(assuming group is ID, obj) to subset the `.SD` (subset of data.table)

```
dt[, .SD[which.max(as.POSIXct(MR_time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))], by = .(ID, obj)]
```